# Check for an image in Rich Text Field

Tags: richtext

I have a DIV wrapping a Rich Text field.  I would like to add a class name to the DIV only if an image is present in the text field.  Is there a way to check for an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`in` operator](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator) to search for a substring in your markup.

```
{% set imageExists = '<img' in entry.body.getRawContent() %}
{% set classAttr = imageExists ? 'with-image' : '' %}

<div class="{{ classAttr }}">
    {{ entry.body }}
</div>
```

Another, probably bit more reliable way to test for `<img>` elements is to use the [Retcon](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) plugin, which uses DOMdocument to parse the markup.

A combination of `retconOnly` and `length` filters should get you there.

```
{% set imageExists = entry.body|retconOnly('img')|length %}
```

Comment: Thank you...  my code is now like this and works.                              {% set imageExists = block.textArea|retconOnly('img')|length %}
                            {% set classAttr = imageExists ? 'with-image' : '' %}
                            <div class="entryTxt {{ classAttr }}">
                                {{ block.textArea|retconUnwrap('img') }}
                            </div>